Importrange formula shortening
=QUERY({ IMPORTRANGE('LİNK'!B2;'LİNK'!D1); IMPORTRANGE('LİNK'!B3;'LİNK'!D1); IMPORTRANGE('LİNK'!B4;'LİNK'!D1); 
IMPORTRANGE('LİNK'!B5;'LİNK'!D1); 
IMPORTRANGE('LİNK'!B6;'LİNK'!D1); 
IMPORTRANGE('LİNK'!B7;'LİNK'!D1); 
IMPORTRANGE('LİNK'!B8;'LİNK'!D1); 
IMPORTRANGE('LİNK'!B9;'LİNK'!D1); ...
....
....
....
....
IMPORTRANGE('LİNK'!B123;'LİNK'!D1) };"select * where Col1 is not null AND Col4 matches '.{4,}'")

There are links in the B2:B column on the page named LINK, I want to import all the links at once with importrange. In cell D1 of the page named LINK, the range of the page whose data will be retrieved is written, for example TEST!B2:J200.
In short, go to all links and bring the B2:J200 range of the page called TEST. The link I gave works, but how can I shorten it?

Can you provide a sample spreadsheet containing sample data? Also I believe that there are only 2 columns in your import range (B and D only) if you put it that way so there should be no col4 in your query statement.

But the OP's given formula specifies an import range of just B and D right? So the input array based on the query range input only registers 2 columns, right?

@PatrickdC the OP's formula specifies that URLs should be retrieved from cells 'LİNK'!B5:B123 and that the A1 type range reference should be retrieved from cell 'LİNK'!D1. The A1-type range reference in that cell is specified as TEST!B2:J200.

Oh I see. I did not get that right away due to the lack of a sample spreadsheet.


Here's one approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=let(Σ;tocol(;1); reduce(Σ;tocol('LİNK'!B2:B;1);lambda(a;c;ifna(vstack(if(iserr(+a);Σ;a);iferror(query(importrange(c;'LİNK'!D1);"where Col1 is not null AND Col4 matches '.{4,}'");Σ))))))


what is tocol(;1) and iserr(+a) means in that formula ?
What does the + sign mean here?

+a is used as a shortcut for index(a,1,1). tocol(;1) is one method of creating null header/row when used in conjunction with vstack()

When I apply the unique formula to the data obtained as a result of this formula, uniques do not appear, even though the data is double, what could be the reason, even though the number format is automatic?

How can i fix it? @rockinfreakshow

Use this pattern:
=let( 
  importMultipleRanges_; lambda(spreadsheet_ids; ranges_A1; let(i_;lambda(i;r;let(d;reduce(æ;sequence(5);lambda(f;n;if(iserror(f);importrange(i;upper(left(r;n))&lower(mid(r;n+1;99)));f)));filter(d;byrow(d;lambda(r;len(join("";r)))))));a;hstack(tocol(spreadsheet_ids);tocol(ranges_A1));y;max(bycol(a;lambda(l;index(ifna(xmatch("?*";to_text(l);2;-1))))));s;sequence(y);p;array_constrain(bycol(a;lambda(v;map(s;lambda(i;index(xlookup(i;s/(v<>"");v;;-1))))));y;columns(a));reduce(tocol(æ;2);sequence(counta(p)/2);lambda(r;i;vstack(r;i_(index(p;i;1);index(p;i;2))))))); 

  data; importMultipleRanges_('LİNK'!B5:B123; 'LİNK'!D1); 

  query(data; "where Col1 is not null and Col4 matches '.{4,}' "; 0) 
)

See
let() and
lambda().
